# Airflow webserver not responding (ome workers seem to have died and gunicorn did not restart them as expected)

Tags: airflow

We recently started seeing that airflow-webserver stops to respond. The service still appears to be running when running `systemctl status airflow-webserver`, but the logs are filled with errors and the wb service is not responding. The errors in the

```
Sep 14 06:56:45 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-14 06:56:45,662] {{cli.py:990}} ERROR - [0 / 0] Some workers seem to have died and gunicorn did not restart them as expected
Sep 14 06:56:56 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-14 06:56:56,701] {{cli.py:990}} ERROR - [0 / 0] Some workers seem to have died and gunicorn did not restart them as expected
Sep 14 06:57:07 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-14 06:57:07,738] {{cli.py:990}} ERROR - [0 / 0] Some workers seem to have died and gunicorn did not restart them as expected
```

I have gone backwards in the log to the last line before these started occuring (`journalctl -u airflow-webserver -a | grep -v "Some workers seem to have died and gunicorn did not restart them as expected" | tail -n 100`) and the last errors that I find look like this:

```
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,503] {{base.py:601}} ERROR - Add Permission on Menu Error: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [SQL: SELECT TOP 1 ab_view_menu.id AS ab_view_menu_id, ab_view_menu.name AS ab_view_menu_name
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: FROM ab_view_menu
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: WHERE ab_view_menu.name = ?]
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [parameters: ('Logs',)]
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,504] {{base.py:600}} ERROR - (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [SQL: SELECT TOP 1 ab_view_menu.id AS ab_view_menu_id, ab_view_menu.name AS ab_view_menu_name
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: FROM ab_view_menu
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: WHERE ab_view_menu.name = ?]
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [parameters: [immutabledict({})]]
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1203, in _execute_context
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: conn = self._revalidate_connection()
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 473, in _revalidate_connection
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: "Can't reconnect until invalid "
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 598, in _add_permissions_menu
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: self.sm.add_permissions_menu(name)
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/manager.py", line 1211, in add_permissions_menu
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: self.add_view_menu(view_menu_name)
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/sqla/manager.py", line 431, in add_view_menu
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: view_menu = self.find_view_menu(name)
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/sqla/manager.py", line 420, in find_view_menu
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: return self.get_session.query(self.viewmenu_model).filter_by(name=name).first()
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3397, in first
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: ret = list(self[0:1])
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3171, in __getitem__
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: return list(res)
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3503, in __iter__
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: return self._execute_and_instances(context)
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3528, in _execute_and_instances
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1014, in execute
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: return meth(self, multiparams, params)
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1133, in _execute_clauseelement
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: distilled_params,
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1208, in _execute_context
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: e, util.text_type(statement), parameters, None, None
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1512, in _handle_dbapi_exception
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 178, in raise_
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: raise exception
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1203, in _execute_context
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: conn = self._revalidate_connection()
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: File "/usr/local/airflow/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 473, in _revalidate_connection
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: "Can't reconnect until invalid "
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [SQL: SELECT TOP 1 ab_view_menu.id AS ab_view_menu_id, ab_view_menu.name AS ab_view_menu_name
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: FROM ab_view_menu
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: WHERE ab_view_menu.name = ?]
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [parameters: [immutabledict({})]]
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,505] {{base.py:601}} ERROR - Add Permission on Menu Error: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [SQL: SELECT TOP 1 ab_view_menu.id AS ab_view_menu_id, ab_view_menu.name AS ab_view_menu_name
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: FROM ab_view_menu
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: WHERE ab_view_menu.name = ?]
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [parameters: [immutabledict({})]]
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,508] {{base.py:414}} INFO - Registering class SlaMissModelView on menu SLA Misses
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,508] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/action/<string:name>/<pk> ['GET', 'POST']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,508] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/action_post ['POST']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,510] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/add ['GET', 'POST']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,510] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/api ['GET']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,510] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/api/column/add/<col_name> ['GET']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,510] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/api/column/edit/<col_name> ['GET']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,511] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/api/create ['POST']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,511] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/api/delete/<pk> ['DELETE']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,511] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/api/get/<pk> ['GET']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,511] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/api/read ['GET']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,511] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/api/readvalues ['GET']
Sep 13 05:12:17 semaf1-dk1.mid.dom airflow[1833]: [2020-09-13 05:12:17,512] {{baseviews.py:266}} INFO - Registering route /slamiss/api/update/<pk> ['PUT']
```

It seems that it is only the webserver that stops responding. The scheduler is running and jobs are executed as usual.

It is a possibility that this is related to database maintenance (it usually happens during weekends where database maintenance is allowed), but I would have hoped that Airflow would recover from that once the database is live again. We are running Airflow 1.10.11, SQL Server for the Airflow database and Red Hat Enterprise Server.

Running `systemctl restart airflow-webserver` always resolves the issue.

Has anyone else observed similar issues or ideas to how we can resolve this?

Comment: It's also noticed in airflow docker image 1.10.14

Answer (score 0):

It is rather obvious. Notice this one line:

```
[2020-09-13 05:12:17,505] {{base.py:601}} ERROR - Add Permission on Menu Error:
(sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
```

So you'll have to find the one transaction, which is either wrongful or won't get committed.

Comment: Right, but this is within the Apache Airflow / SQLAlchemy application code. The question is why this occur?

If this is isolated to our environment (which, is a little unusual in that we use SQL Server) or is it more common